# Model Start Event Cascade through BPMN

Tags: bpmn

I'm trying to model the following (simplified) workflow. Each start event has a route to the `Main Task` as well as an alternative route which will trigger the "previous" start event.

My problem: if `Start Event 2` is triggered through a path from `Start Event 3` it should not be possible to trigger `Start Event 1` any more (red path): `3->2` is ok, `2->1` is ok, but **not** `3->1`!

[image]

What would be the "right" solution here? Should I create an alternative `Start Event 2` when it's triggered through `Start Event 3` (seem to be redundant). Or should I solve this somehow through a logic gate `if triggered through Start Event 3 then ...  else ...` (seems to be over complicated). Or is there a better solution?

PS. I tried to find a better stack exchange site for modelling but it seems 99% of the questions regarding BPMN are posted here. But I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Start Events must not have an incoming Edge. It is not allowed by the BPMN standard. So you should replace your Start Events 2 and 3 within the process with intermediate Events.

The decission logic to skip or execute the Intermediate Event now representing the event of what was before Start Event 3 could be implemented in an Event Based Gateway, describing on the Edges which path to take under which condition.

[image: BPMN Model example]

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that start events can't have anything incoming. A followup question, two edges connecting TO event 2, should I go trough an xor event here, or would that be just eye candy? `Start event 2` and `Create Parameter für Event 2` would connect to an xor gate and the gate would connect to `event 2`

Comment: Reading up on intermediate events and event based gates, I made a second answer which seems to be "better" then yours. But I'm not sure, maybe I missunderstood the correct usage of events. I would appreciate Feedback.

Comment: this is the source I used to understand the event based gateway: http://www.processmodeling.info/posts/demystifying-the-event-driven-gateway/

Comment: I had your solution also first in mind and first of all it is a valid model. But if the Process requires to pass the "event 2" after starting with "event 3" then this is only possible in my model using the intermediate event and not possible in yours. If this is not a requirement your model is simpler. But it depends on the details of the modeled use case.

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with, the state of "Start Event 2" is reached by the event itself or by the "Create Paramters for Event 2" task. With the task I see no need to specify the state explicitly because it must have been reached by the task. I see why you are formally not wrong specifying the state "twice", but in my view it's redundant, isn't it?!

Comment: note: I made followup question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025239/when-to-use-an-event-when-to-use-a-task-in-bpmn

Comment: Also an additional question, according to [specs](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.2/PDF) see Table 7.2 on page 35, the is no joining event based gate. In addition to that, in your case it's not connected to the actual event itself. In what way might those aspects create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Simulat's answer I found a alternative solution which I think is the better fit. The red path should not be possible because of the logic gate with the red circle (the top path is only viable if `Start Event 3` has not occurred).

The problem I have with Simulat's answer are the intermediate events and the event based gate. Since there are no "real" events on those points so I think they should be xor logic gates, but I'm not sure. Feedback is welcome:

[image]